# Multiple setting of UserDefaults resulting in slower display

Tags: swift, performance, memory, nsuserdefaults

I have quite a broaden app in which I store lots of data. CLLocation ones, Arrays, CGPoints and so on. From time to time there's a need to save all these variables on the device, so I use UserDefaults. Yet, after some time of switching through ViewControllers and simply using the app (constant changing of data => constant saving it) I get to the point where everything runs slowly.

Now, suppose I have more or less three 2-dimensional Arrays and lets say 5 Ints I want to save to UserDefaults.

Every time I change one of the variables I "update" it by the same command:

```
UserDefaults.standard.set(data, forKey: "UDdata").
```

So every time I want the data to change, I change it through that particular comment. I guess every time I do it I should somehow get rid of the previous data for key UDdata and just then set it with the same key string? Information on that matter would be useful. Thanks in advance

Comment: `UserDefaults` is not the proper place to store app data. It's meant for small values like preferences.

Comment: while @rmaddy is certainly right, I dont think misusing UserDefaults here is your problem. I never experienced to slow down at least ;) Anyway, i'd be more inclined that it is general memory leakage

Comment: I would strongly suggest using the ‘time profile’ instrument in Instruments.app to investigate your problem directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is you misusing the Userdefaults. They are to store small values like flags to detect first launches, preference and etc. Instead of storing data in Userdefaults just try to use CoreData or SQLite. Which is way more easier to use too.

CoreData :
https://www.raywenderlich.com/145809/getting-started-core-data-tutorial

SQLite :
https://www.raywenderlich.com/123579/sqlite-tutorial-swift

Comment: I am facing the same problem and I am not using a huge amount of data. Only a single 12 digit string identifier. Sometimes, (especially after reinstalls) it takes forever for the set operation to be completed. Also, it's strange that it happens mostly after reinstall as a reinstall (delete and install) should erase all previous data.